# install haddock on windows GHCi 8.0.1

Tags: haskell, haddock

My question is very simple, how do I install haddock?

I'm using GHCi version 8.0.1 in windows.. Is haddock compatible with windows GHCI?

Comment: Potential close voters: please don't use the "general computing" close reason if you have absolutely no clue about what the question is about.

Comment: Hi man, I'm a bit new to stackoverflow, and I didn't understand what you meant... Does my question breaks any kind of rule? I can't make haddock run and I'm trying...

Comment: It's been a while since I used Haskell on Windows, but I'm pretty much sure it is compatible. Are you using *cabal* or *stack* to manage your packages?

Comment: (And don't worry, your question is fine. I wrote that because someone used the system to complain about your question for a spurious reason.)

Comment: I'm using WinGHCi it allows me to do what i need without no commands basiclly... I do my .hs on sublime and open in winGHCi... I dont really Know what i'm using (cabal or stack)... I'm just starting programming so I have not my knowledge sorry

Comment: That's fine. Just one more question, to see if we are on the same page: what do you need Haddock for?

Comment: I need it to generate one HTML doc of my program..

I need to use this command, but i can't for now :

haddock -h -o doc/html Main.hs 

And it creats an HTML file

Comment: I assume you are running this command in the Windows command prompt, and not in WinGHCi, right?

Comment: Oh, I'm so retarded you're right, It runs on command prompt... I was trying to use it from ghci.exe... Damn I'm stupid. Thank you man

Comment: No worries. By the way, I should mention that *cabal* (and/or *stack*) are tools used to build and install Haskell-powered software. If you really didn't have Haddock, `cabal install haddock` would probably be enough to get it installed. (Given that you mentioned WinGHCi, though, odds are you have the Haskell Platform of which it is a part installed in your computer, and so it would be surprising if you didn't have the other command-line tools included in it, such as `ghc`, `cabal`, `haddock`, etc.)

Comment: I did download it anyway, but i didn't had haddock in the lib folder(where cabal is for example) so maybe i didn't had it installed, anyway, my problem was using the command on the wrong place, so dumb...    


Thank you a lot, i was here losing almost one hour already trying to find what i was doing wrong, and it was so simple.